# MySQLDump backup and restore on different schema same server

Tags: mysql

I have a staging MySQL db where I had created intermediate tables for data load. I want to migrate this db to Prod but with only the tables needed in production (along with all the routines, events and triggers) using `mysqldump`.

Before I hand over the script to the platform team to carry this out in production I wanted to test it out locally, so we created a separate schema on the same server and we are trying out the following:

We tried out the `mysqldump` command without the `--add-drop database`, instead used `--no-create-db` because I am concerned that during the restore process, the "use stage" statements in the stored procedure definitions might change the db and wipe out my stage db.  The result was that the tables got copied over, but the routines did not.

Is there a way to make this work while:

A. select subset of tables along with all routines and events

B. restore them in a different schema

C. WITHOUT risking wipeout of the original schema?

Comment: B: In the output from a `mysqldump` statement does not change schema, unless  the option `-A, --all-databases` is used.

Comment: C: `mysqldump` does not wipeout anything in the original schema.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
mysqldump -u username -p password  --hex-blob -R -e --triggers database_name > database_name.sql
```

You can add or remove options from the dump commands based on your needs.

`--single-transaction` --- > option if you don't want or can't do table locks

`-d`                   --- > -d is `--no-data` for short.

`-R`                   --- > Also consider adding `--routines` (-R for short ) if you're database has stored procedures/functions

`-B`                   --- > Include the `CREATE DATABASE` command.  `--databases` dbname (shorthand: -B dbname)

`-r`                   --- > To avoid having the character set of your shell interfere with encoding, -r schema.sql is preferred over > schema.sql. Also a good idea to specify the character set explicitly
with --default-character-set=utf8 (or whatever). You'll still want to check the set names at the top of the dump file. I've been caught in MySQL charset encoding hell before

`--routines`           --- > Also consider adding --routines if you're database has stored procedures/functions

`--hex-blob` if you have blob data type in your database